# Should I attach a different Firebase AppCheck token to each request?

Tags: firebase, react-native, security, firebase-app-check

I am developing a React Native app, we got some a couple bruteforce attacks so we want to protect our backend with Firebase Appcheck.

1. Is it useful to use a new token for each request ?
2. Is it worth it to cache it for it's lifetime and then renew it so i can save some network requests ?
3. Should I use it only on sensitives requests ?

Thanks !